# How to run pre build gradle java project in intellij

Tags: eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea

I have been using eclipse. Recently, I started using intellij IDE.

My project is core java project with gradle as build tool. In eclipse, i used to build the project through command like and import it into the project. Then i used to run it without any issues.

One of the below command i used to use frequently.

```
gradle -s --refresh dependencies clean build eclipse  -x findbugsMain -x checkstyleMain
gradle -s --refresh dependencies clean build -x findbugsMain -x checkstyleMain 
gradle build -x findbugsMain -x checkstyleMain
```

Now when i try imported my projects as module in intellij and try to run, it tries to build everything again and fails with error.

I do not want intellij to build the project again but to use the already build one which i did through command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you build form command line first, then build from IDE with Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using** option set to **Gradle**, IDE will reuse previous build cache results, provided that there were no changes since last Gradle build. It is important to note 2 things:

- Build from IDE should be invoked as Build | **Build** action, not **Rebuild**. The Rebuild IDE action is not the same as Gradle clean build task. With clean build Gradle will re-use cache (if enabled) and will not rebuild all the classes and process all the resources if there were no changes. In case of the IDE **Rebuild** action - IDE will mark previous build results as "dirty" and will recompile all the classes and resources.
- The Gradle you configure for the project in IDE settings must be the same as you use in command line. To be sure the same Gradle is used it is easier of all to configure to use Gradle wrapper for project.

Also if you do not want for the IDE to build at all you can remove **Make** action from **Before launch** section of your [Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html).